# How to disable accelerators when typing text in GTK+

Tags: python, gtk

I'm using some predefined accelerators connected with certain hot keys. Is it possible to temporarily disable them? I don't want to change the hot keys, in order not to confuse users. The accelerators are activated when typing into a combo box, which really is unacceptable.

Comment: What are you accelerators and what characters are you typing?

Comment: It's not an issue anymore, but to ask your question the accelerator defined for main window connected pressing the "s" key with some functionality of the app. I was trying to somehow disable the shortcut for the time when the user is typing something into text box.

Comment: Side note regarding the bounty: The question has "python" in the tags but as far as I'm concerned this is really a GTK+ question, so any language should be fine.

Comment: Another note: **Please** disregard the "It's not an issue anymore" comment. It's not an issue anymore for them but the problem in general persists.

Comment: @user3484510 You should post your own answer to this (as it looks that others may have the same issue)

Answer (score 2):

[I asked this again on the GTK+ mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2016-June/msg00000.html) and the people there had two suggestions that came with real-life implementations from their own projects (not linked here but you can check the thread if you want to see them):

1. Intercept and handle *all* key presses, thus overriding GTK+'s normal mechanism and allowing you to make exceptions for your accelerators.
2. Having a list of accelerators that you remove manually when a text editing widget gets focus, then add them again when the widget loses focus. In GTK+ 3 this is accomplished with `gtk_application_set_accels_for_action`.

In the thread I linked you can find example code for both approaches. The second approach even has an example in GTK+ 2 and one in GTK+ 3.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot disable them. They will receive any key stroke that is not consumed by the focused Window.